# Como limitar o envio de e-mail a cada 24 horas?

Tags: php, javascript, html

De uma forma que fosse feito por javascript e salvo diretamente no lado do cliente e não pelo servidor?

```php
     <?php

         // UTF-8
         header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

          date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

        //se nao funcionar remover
        //if (isset($_POST['BTEnvia'])) {

           // from the form
         $nome = $_POST['nome'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $telefone = $_POST['telefone']; 
         $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];


         //REMETENTE --> ESTE EMAIL TEM QUE SER VALIDO DO DOMINIO
         //==================================================== 
         $email_remetente = "suporte@site.com"; // deve ser uma conta de email do seu dominio 
         //====================================================

         //Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
         //==================================================== 
         //EDIT 10/10 14:15 $email_destinatario = "suporte@site.com"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
         $email_reply = "$email"; 
         $email_assunto = "Nova mensagem no formulário"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
         //====================================================

        // ENVIA e-mail para um determinado e-mail de acordo com a hora do dia
        //======================================================
        $date = new \DateTime();

        $date->setTime(18,00,00);

        $dateNow = new \DateTime();

        //antes de meio dia
        $email_destinatario = 'email@site.com'; 

        //Depois de meio dia
        if($dateNow > $date) {
            $email_destinatario = 'contato@site.com';
        }


               $subject = "Nova mensagem BR";
               $to = 'contato@site.com';
          //======================================================   


         $email_conteudo = "<b>Nome:</b>: $nome \n"; 
         $email_conteudo .= "<b>Email:</b>  $email \n";
         $email_conteudo .= "<b>Assunto:</b> $telefone \n"; 
         $email_conteudo .= "<b>Mensagem:</b> $mensagem \n"; 



               // send the email

                $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );


                mail($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers); //$body 12-10



        ?>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Passa um cron contando se passou um dia e muda o status para não enviado de novo e libera o envio. Claro que precisa validar quantidade mínima que ele pode está fazendo envio.